Applescript to set a reminder with date but no time
I would like to edit a reminder in Applescript and for each undated reminder, set today's date, but no time. (Not midnight - NO time.)
tell application "Reminders"
    repeat with r in every reminder
        set creationDate to creation date of r
        if (due date of r is missing value) then
            set due date of r to current date
        end if
    end repeat
end tell

This doesn't work - it sets the due date to today with the current time. I've tried setting the time to 0, but that just sets midnight. Null doesn't work at all.

What does no time mean in practice?

I figured it out. The only needed change is set allday due date instead.
